# Selenium AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'native_events_enabled'

Tags: python, selenium

I input selenium firefox like this in my code,
I am running python 2.7 on windows and using bash with conda

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox('./firefoxdriver')
```

This is what my terminal says:

```
C:\Users\Vinko\Desktop\predictBO-master>bash oakniiv@vinko:/mnt/c/Users/Vinko/Desktop/predictBO-master$ source activate predictboba (predictboba) oakniiv@vinko:/mnt/c/Users/Vinko/Desktop/predictBO-master$ python demotrade_tf.py Traceback (most recent call last):   File "demotrade_tf.py", line 99, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox('./firefoxdriver')   File "/home/oakniiv/anaconda2/envs/predictboba/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.NATIVE_EVENTS_ALLOWED and self.profile.native_events_enabled) AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'native_events_enabled'
```

I do not know what else to give you, it looks like the problem is in firefox itself?

It works when I do `driver = webdriver.Firefox()`

Comment: Please read why a [**`screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea`**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based HTML and code trials.

Comment: Do you want to pass path to `FirefoxProfile` or to `geckodriver`? Note that when you creates instance of `Chrome()` with just a single string argument - new value assigned to `executable_path`, but in case of `Firefox()` - new value assigned to `firefox_profile`. If you want to set new path to `geckodriver`, you need to make it explicitly - `driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='./firefoxdriver')`

Answer (score 2):

You passed a `str` as a `FirefoxProfile`, which is the problem:

```
 driver = webdriver.Firefox('./firefoxdriver')
```

You want:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('./firefoxdriver')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

If you did not intend to use a custom profile, then you can use defaults:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Comment: Sorry, edited your answer by mistake. I meant to edit mine (which is not showing up for some reason).