# What is "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'native_events_enabled" error? it appears when using selenium with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

Here my requirement is, have to log in one web page using the below-mentioned block of code. using 2.7.13, selenium 2.45.0, Windows 10.

```
     class WebJIRA:

       driverpath = "path\to\geckodriver.exe"
       driver = webdriver.Firefox(driverpath)
       ConfigRead.defaultvalues()

       def login_page(self,username):
         WebJIRA.webdriver.get(jirausername)

     main = WebJIRA()
     main.login_jira()
```

but it throws below error.

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 46, in __init__
    self.NATIVE_EVENTS_ALLOWED and self.profile.native_events_enabled)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'native_events_enabled'
```

Can anyone please help me to get through this one. I'm new to python. 
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48307531/selenium-attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-native-events-enabled)  explains how to deal with firefoxprofile when it has been passing as 'str', in my case I have to pass a variable(which contains geckodriver path) but both errors are same.

Comment: I couldn't understand that both questions is the same and can you please explain what I have to do with this in my case?

Answer (score 2):

This is the signature of the Firefox webdriver:

```
class selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver(firefox_profile=None, firefox_binary=None, timeout=30, capabilities=None, proxy=None, executable_path='geckodriver', options=None, log_path='geckodriver.log', firefox_options=None, service_args=None)
```

The first argument is a firefox profile, not the driver executable. You'll have to use a keyword argument.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=driverpath)
```

I guess you copied an example using the `webdriver.Chrome`, which takes `executable_path` as it's first argument. They *do not* have the same signature.

Answer (score 0):

@jbch answer was pretty much in the right direction. You need to pass the *Key* `executable_path` along with *Value* pertaining to the *absolute path* of the *GeckoDriver* binary as follows. Additionally, as you are on *Windows OS* the *absolute path* of the *GeckoDriver* binary must be:

- Within single quotes (i.e. `''`).
- Preceeded by the raw (i.e. `r`) switch.
- Path seperated by single front slash (i.e. `\`)
- The line of code will be:

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\geckodriver.exe')
  ```